# Intuitive approach to cofinality

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Can someone give me intuitive explanation of cofinality?

I pretty much understand what does it mean for a subset $x$ in $y$ to be cofinal (something like being dense when going from the left to the right), but when defining cofinality of $y$, one first says that

$$\text{cof}(y) = \text{min}\left\{\text{otp}(x) | x \text{ cofinal in } y\right\}$$

On the other hand, one states that this is the same as if we take $\text{card}(x)$ instead of $\text{otp}(x)$ in the above definition, but I wonder why..

Comment: It's always good to give a context at the start of your question. "Cofinality" is a term used in a several different contexts.

Comment: In may case it concerns set theoretical approach. Namely, I've read the next:
To get some more information on cardinal exponentiation, we need to measure how “fast” a cardinal can be approximated using smaller cardinals.
Definitions:
a) A set x ⊆ λ is cofinal in the limit ordinal λ if ∀α < λ ∃ξ ∈ x α < ξ .
b) The cofinality of a limit ordinal λ is
cof(λ) = min {otp(x)|x ⊆ λ is cofinal in λ}.
c) A limit ordinal λ is regular if cof(λ) = λ ; otherwise λ is singular.        But still I have problem with intuitive understanding and especially with the above equation that I've mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that a cofinality is *always* a cardinal. In other words, if $\alpha$ is an ordinal which is not a cardinal, then $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)<\alpha$.

To see why, enumerate $\alpha$ by its cardinality, and start constructing a strictly increasing sequence which agrees on both the enumeration and the natural ordering of $\alpha$. You either get stuck at some ordinal below $|\alpha|$, or that you get that there is a cofinal sequence of length and order type $|\alpha|$.

If the cofinal sequence you ended up with was not of a cardinal order type, repeat the process. This is a decreasing sequence of ordinals, so it has to stop: exactly when the cofinal sequence is a cardinal, and it is not hard to check that this sequence is indeed cofinal in $\alpha$.

---

Note that it is often the case that "the smallest ..." ends up with a cardinal. It's not *always*, sure, but it isn't peculiar for cofinality. Other definitions include the Hartogs and Lindenbaum numbers.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24982/cofinality-and-its-consequences/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389420/why-does-every-countable-limit-ordinal-have-cofinality-omega/ might be relevant.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What are Lindenbaum numbers? Google doesn't tell me :)

Comment: @Achilles: If $x$ is a set, the Lindenbaum number of $x$, $\aleph^*(x)$, is the least ordinal such that there is no surjection from $x$ onto it.